# How to create a directive that provides values for ng-options?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, ng-options

I've got select elements that have the same options across the whole app, but may look a bit differently, e.g. selects for user's birthday (day, month, year).

Is there a way to create a directive that would provide values/expression for `ng-options`?

E.g. `<select my-options-months></select>`, where `my-options-months` would automatically create options with values `1..12` using `ng-options` directive.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Updated answer**
Your directive would like this:

```
var myapp = angular.module('myapp', []);
myapp.controller('FirstCtrl', function ($scope) {
    $scope.selectedMonth = 3
})
    .directive('myOptionsMonths', function ($compile) {

    return {
        priority: 1001, // compiles first
        terminal: true, // prevent lower priority directives to compile after it
        compile: function (element, attrs) {
            element.attr("ng-options", "m for m in months");
            element.removeAttr('my-options-months'); // necessary to avoid infinite compile loop      
            var fn = $compile(element);
            return function (scope) {
                scope.months = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12]
                fn(scope);
            };
        }
    }
})
```

Please, checkout fiddle with example http://jsfiddle.net/KN9xx/39/

Comment: Thanks! 

One more question: how can I access property from `ng-model` in this directive, so that I can set the default value for `ng-model` property if it's null/undefined?

BTW. Could you explain shortly why `terminal` option is required here?

Comment: Note to anyone looking for an answer: It is not required to have a terminal directive (nor do you have to compile it yourself. All you need is a priority >0 (e.g. 1), so your directive compiles before the `select` directive. (A more complex example that also assigns a default value to `ngModel` can be found **[here](http://jsfiddle.net/ExpertSystem/2yNt3/)**.)

Comment: @ExpertSystem, I can't figure out why your fiddle does not work with Angular 1.4.x and above? Is there a difference in the compilation order now? Any chance you can provide a fiddle that works with the latest Angular?

Comment: @c05mic: (Un)fortunately, there has been a major refactoring for `ngOptions` and in 1.4.x it is a directive of its own. So you **do** need to have a terminal directive and manually compile (more or less as shown in this answer). Here is a (slightly improved) [live demo](http://codepen.io/ExpertSystem/pen/OyZZdd?editors=101).

Comment: @ExpertSystem Thanks a lot for that. That works perfectly for me.

Answer (score 0):

If you are planning to create a range of values in select just put it in a template. And if the range has to be dynamic just link it to a attribute in a directive.

```
app.directive('myOptionsMonths', function(){
  return {
    scope: {
      myOptionsMonths:"@"
    },
    link: function(scope,e, a){
      var N = +a.myOptionsMonths;
      scope.values  = Array.apply(null, {length: N}).map(Number.call, Number);
    },
    template: "<select ng-model='t' ng-options='o for o in values'></select>"
  };
}); 

<my-options-months my-options-months="10"></my-options-months>
```

Demo: http://plnkr.co/edit/tL694zGr5tZJq5L4pwEA?p=preview

Comment: Thanks, but I'd like to avoid creating the whole select element to be able to easily add any additional attributes to select element itself without having to create bindings for each possible attribute in my directive.

Answer (score 0):

may be with a different approach with a filter like:

```
.filter('range', function () {
        return function (input, min, max, padding){
            min = parseInt(min);
            max = parseInt(max);
            padding = padding ? padding : false;
            for (var i=min; i<=max; i++){
                input.push(padding ? ("00" + i).slice (-2) : i + '');
            }
            return input;
        };
    })
```