# How to require a directive with lower priority if given directive is "terminal"?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

This is a follow-up on https://stackoverflow.com/a/24058594/261673 where I asked how to make a directive that provides default options for `ng-options` directive.

I'm trying to provide a default value in case the value defined by `ng-model` is not defined.

I've added `require: 'ngModel'` to the directive options and the following code to `link` function returned by `compile` function:

`if(!$ctrl.$viewValue) {
  $ctrl.$setViewValue($scope.months[0]);
}`

where `$ctrl` is `ngModelController`. It <del>works fine</del> (see edit) if I set priority to 0, however, if I leave it as it originally was (`1001`) it no longer works. I suspect that this directive is compiled before `ngModel` and because it's `terminal` `ngModel` is never compiled and something breaks.

Is there a way to somehow make it work without changing priority to 0?

Here's Plunker with the whole code: http://plnkr.co/edit/IZ0eyqHoqwSVPlhxI98X?p=preview

EDIT: Actually, it doesn't work fine with priority 0 as well. For some reason every second time the option in any select is changed, the value gets undefined and there are empty options with `? undefined:undefined ?` and `?` values...

Comment: Why do you need it to be `terminal` ?

Comment: That's what I asked about the author of the answer to the original question :) As far as I understand it, because you're adding a new directive to the element (`ng-options`), you don't want any other directives to be compiled at this point. Instead, you want to compile the whole element after you add `ng-options`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know why the original answerer thought they have to use `terminal: true`, but you don't have to.

All you need it to make sure your directive compiles before the `select` directive (which executes at priority 0), so any priority >0 will do (in fact using priority 1 works fine).

Then you can access the required directive's controller as usual:

```
app.directive('myOptionsMonths', function ($timeout) {
    return {
        priority: 1,
        require: 'ngModel',
        compile: function (tElem, tAttrs) {
            tAttrs.$set('ngOptions', 'month for month in months');
            tAttrs.$set('myOptionsMonths', null);
            return function (scope, elem, attrs, ctrl) {
                scope.months = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12];
                $timeout(function () {
                    if (ctrl.$viewValue === undefined) {
                        ctrl.$setViewValue(scope.months[0]);
                    }
                });
            };
        }
    };
});
```

<sub>You still need to use `$timeout`, because the `NgModelController`'s properties are not set yet</sub>

---

See, also, this **[short demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ExpertSystem/2yNt3/)**.

Comment: Thanks! Like I mentioned before, I think `terminal: true` was to ensure that in the first compilation pass, only this directive gets compiled and the rest gets compiled in the second pass together with `ng-options` added in the first pass. It seems to make sense, but it looks like it's not really necessary.

EDIT: I've just noticed that your directive doesn't compile explicitly the element like mine does, so there are no 2 compilation passes - that's probably why it doesn't need to be terminal and simply higher priority is enough.

Comment: Exactly :) `terminal` doesn't prevent other directives with higher (or equal) priorities to get executed anyway, so there is no much point in using it.

Answer (score 0):

I *think* I've figured it out, however, it looks like a terrible hack.

Looking at the source code of `$compileProvider.directive` function, I've found a way to access `ngModelController` without using `require: 'ngModel'`:

```
$timeout(function () {
  var ctrl = $element['data']('$ngModelController');

  if (ctrl.$viewValue) {
    ctrl.$setViewValue($scope.months[0]);
  }
});
```

It's very similar to the previous code, but this time it gets access to `ngModelController` via compiled element. `$timeout` is need, because otherwise `ctrl.$viewValue` was always `NaN` at this point, even if model value was set, so it was always overwriting model value.

Here's updated Plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/h5ZPqTdyrZ0zTyyDcdei?p=preview